# Magento 2 InstallSchema not being executed

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I've written a basic Magento 2 custom module. The module is able to register with Magento 2 when I run `bin/magento module:enable <module name>`. I've checked the `setup_module` table and the module entry is there and the module is enabled.

I'm having a problem getting my `Setup/InstallSchema.php` to run. Doesn't matter what I do, the schema installer is never executed. I am assuming this is because when I first performed the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command I had a blank `InstallSchema.php`. Disabling and re-enabling the module doesn't do anything. I've checked the database and Magento doesn't appear to use the database to keep track of the module `setup_version`. I've tried finding where on disk Magento tracks the currently installed `setup_version` but so far I've drawn a blank. I know that Magento can call into my module because it is executing the `Setup/InstallData.php` file quite happily.

Anybody any ideas how I can force Magento 2 to execute my `Setup/InstallSchema.php` file?

Answer (score 7):

you are right magento executes `InstallSchema` once when `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command is executed. You can create a `UpgradeSchema` for changes after installation.

Follow the steps below to convert your InstallSchema to UpgradeSchema.

1) Make a copy of current `InstallSchema` file and rename it to `UpgradeSchema`.

2) Edit `UpgradeSchema.php` and find replace:-

```
{ InstallSchema } => { UpgradeSchema }

 { public function install } => { public function upgrade }
```

3) change `setup_version="1.0.0"` to `setup_version="1.0.1"` in `/app/code/vender/module/etc/module.xml`

4) Execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Hope it will work.... :)

Comment: I believe that if you delete the row from the `setup_module` table matching the name of your module that it should then run the `InstallSchema`.

Comment: Also ensure that the namespace in Setup\InstallSchema.php is correct